# How to solve my Buildozer Error in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I have got the following error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/cha/Desktop/windows/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1276, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/cha/Desktop/windows/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/cha/Desktop/windows/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 725, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/cha/Desktop/windows/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/cha/Desktop/windows/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/cha/Desktop/windows/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 566, in build_recipes
    recipe.prepare_build_dir(arch.arch)
  File "/home/cha/Desktop/windows/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 617, in prepare_build_dir
    self.unpack(arch)
  File "/home/cha/Desktop/windows/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 480, in unpack
    sh.tar('xf', extraction_filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 1566, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 822, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 879, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/tar xf /home/cha/Desktop/windows/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2_image/SDL2_image-2.0.4.tar.gz

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
/usr/bin/tar: SDL2_image-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/webp.framework/Resources: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Resources’: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/tar: SDL2_image-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/webp.framework/webp: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/webp’: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/tar: SDL2_image-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/webp.framework/Headers: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Headers’: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/tar: SDL2_image-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/webp.framework/Versions/Current: Cannot create symlink to ‘A’: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=mc --bootstrap=sdl2
--requirements=python3,kivy,plyer,kivymd --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/cha/Desktop/windows/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a"
--ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
    # ENVIRONMENT:
    #     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
    #     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/cha-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1742,unix/cha-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1742'
    #     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
    #     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
    #     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
    #     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
    #     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
    #     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
    #     LANGUAGE = 'en_IN:en'
    #     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
    #     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
    #     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
    #     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
    #     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
    #     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1594'
    #     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
    #     PWD = '/home/cha/Desktop/windows'
    #     LOGNAME = 'cha'
    #     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
    #     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
    #     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
    #     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
    #     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
    #     WINDOWPATH = '2'
    #     HOME = '/home/cha'
    #     USERNAME = 'cha'
    #     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
    #     LANG = 'en_IN'
    #     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
    #     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
    #     VTE_VERSION = '6003'
    #     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/4aae2984_6658_4b83_a5e1_2d7d5b6fe0e8'
    #     INVOCATION_ID = '6ff3666157294ba59c1f423a73c15656'
    #     MANAGERPID = '1400'
    #     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
    #     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
    #     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
    #     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
    #     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
    #     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
    #     USER = 'cha'
    #     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.123'
    #     DISPLAY = ':0'
    #     SHLVL = '1'
    #     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
    #     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
    #     JOURNAL_STREAM = '8:37102'
    #     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
    #     PATH = '/home/cha/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
    #     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
    #     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
    #     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
    #     OLDPWD = '/home/cha'
    #     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/cha/.buildozer/android/packages'
    #     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
    #     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
    #     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
    #     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
    # 
    # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
    # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
    # Please read the full log, and search for it before
    # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
    # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Here's Buildozer init-

```
# (str) Title of your application title = Mc

# (str) Package name package.name = mc

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging) package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files) source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1) version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all) orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible. android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path = '/home/cha/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path = '/home/cha/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = True

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64 android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output)) log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True) warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

for me, the issue was the shared folder. I used Ubuntu on VirtualBox, I copied the files from the shared folder to the VM and also deleted the `.buildozer` folder. then it worked